# Using Load Indicator while setState is changing React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having an issue where the page for showing a single item is loading late - I need to be able to hold off loading the page until the object has changed. I put in a console log to check the navigation params, and it does show the id is different when I click each button. **How do I ensure that the new screen data is in the view before presenting the page. So, that it I won't have to return back to the main menu and toggle the view before the changes show?** I'm fairly new to React Native and need assistance.

**JobFinder.js**

```
_renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return(
            <View style={styles.item}>
                 <Text style={{fontSize: 17, fontWeight: '500', color: 'gray'}}>{item.job_title}</Text>   
                 <Text style={{color: '#0dcaf0'}}>{item.is_company_verified == 'true' ? <MaterialCommunityIcons name="check-circle" color={'green'} size={18} /> : <MaterialCommunityIcons name="check-circle-outline" color={'gray'} size={18} />} {item.company_full_name} <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" color={'purple'} size={18} /> <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{item.job_city}, {item.job_state} {item.zip_code}</Text> </Text>
                 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("JobProfile", {id: item.id})}>
                     <Text>View Job</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>   
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        let {jobs, isLoading} = this.state;
        return(
        <View style={{paddingVertical: 2, paddingHorizontal: 2}}>
            <Text style={styles.resume_future_hr}>Find<Text style={{color: '#0dcaf0'}}>Jobs</Text></Text>
              <FlatList 
              data={jobs}
               renderItem={this._renderItem}
               keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />  
        </View>
        )
    }
```

**JobProfile.js**

```
const JobProfile = ({route, navigation}) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const [jobId, setJobId] = useState(route.params.id);
    const [job, setJob] = useState({job_title: '', id: ''})
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('')
    const {promiseInProgress} = usePromiseTracker();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
          console.log("called params" + route.params.id)
           setJobId(route.params.id)  
        });
    
        getToken()
        .then(obj => axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/retrieve_user/${obj.user_id}`, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'X-User-Email': `${obj.email}`, 'X-User-Token': `${obj.authentication_token}` } }))
        .then(response => {
  
          setUser(JSON.stringify(response.data));
          setUserId(response.data.id)
        
         fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/jobs/${jobId}`)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => {
          setJob({...data});
         })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });

        return () => {
          unsubscribe;
        };
      }, [navigation, isFocused, route]);

  const getToken = async (user) => {
    try {
      let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
      let data = JSON.parse(userData);
      let user = JSON.parse(data)
      let userObj = { user_id: JSON.stringify(user.data.data.id), email: JSON.stringify(user.data.data.email), authentication_token: JSON.stringify(user.data.data.authentication_token) }
      
      return userObj
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
  }
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <View style={{ paddingVertical: 5, paddingHorizontal: 14 }}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.9, minHeight: 50, padding: 2, borderColor: 'gray', borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 1, height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.8 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("JobSearch")}>
                     <Text>Return to Search</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>  
                    <Text>Job profile</Text>
 
                    <Text>{job.job_title}</Text>
        
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )

};

export default JobProfile;
```

Comment: Can you just be a bit more specific with the details: Which object are you waiting for and which page should show a loading indicator or something?

Comment: Alright, the JobFinder.js is the screen that has the FlatList..for each flat list item, there is a view Job Button. When you click the view job button, it passes the item's id param to it. The JobProfile.js screen, holds the single item view. When I click the view job button, the params update, but sometimes the view does not show the changes. Essentially, I am getting back item for params id 1 when it should be item for params id 2.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, my solution might work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your navigation function to

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate({name: "JobProfile", key: `JobProfile${item.id}`}, {id: item.id})}>
                     <Text>View Job</Text>
```

**Edit:**

Second option is to try using the `getId` prop on your `Screen` definition, according to [the react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigate). You can do it like so:

```
  <Stack.Screen name="JobProfile" /*I assume that's the name*/ component={whatever} getId={({params}) => params.id}/>
```

Comment: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"JobProfile","key":"JobProfile2"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'JobProfile'?. Works with navigate("JobProfile", {id: item.id})

Comment: Hmmm...perhaps the second solution might work for you.

Comment: The issue here is not the params being passed to JobProfile.js. Its the fact that they're being updated late, when you're switching views. setState doesn't update immediately, until the whole call is complete. I need to hold off on loading the JobProfile.js screen until the record is updated in the view.